# MyPy fails to recognize decorated function's return type

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy

I have an odd mypy failure when using decorators from an installed (via `pip install`) package.
The same decorator written within my app code, works just fine.

I have a function like such:

```
def _subscription_entity(self) -> Optional[SubscriptionEntity]:
   return get_subscription(...)  # get_subscription() is a decorated function
```

MyPy is failing with an error: `Returning Any from function declared to return Optional[SubscriptionEntity]`

However, if I copy the whole decorator code, and place it within my app code (in a separate file, and importing that file instead of package installed one), all works as expected. No errors. I have also tested with changing `_subscription_entity` signature to return an `int` and I get an expected error `Returning Optional[SubscriptionEntity] from function declared to return int`

Why would mypy fail when decorator code lives inside a package, but not when lives inside app code ?

The simplified decorator is as follows

```
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def test_cache(wrapped_func: F) -> F:

    @wraps(wrapped_func)
    def decorated_func(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any)-> F:
        return _handle(wrapped_func, *args, **kwargs)

    return cast(F, decorated_func)

def _handle( wrapped_func: Callable, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> F:
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The decorated function is:

```
@test_cache
def get_subscription(cls, request: GetSubscriptionRequest) -> Optional[SubscriptionEntity]:
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my imported package didn't have the right metadata to let MyPy know that package has typing.
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installed_packages.html?highlight=py.typed#making-pep-561-compatible-packages
After adding `py.typed` to `package_data` in `setup` all worked OK with imported package